# lookup with 2 matching key one in foreign document another in same foreign sub document array mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 3 collections Plan, Group and Time

```
Plan {
  _id: ObjectId,
  group: ObjectId(ref=Group),
  time: ObjectId(ref=Time)
}

Group {
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String
}

Time {
  _id: ObjectId,
  startDate: Date,
  exceptions: [{
    _id: ObjectId
    group: ObjectId(ref=Group)
    startDate: Date
  }]
}
```

I want to get all plans starting today where if today matches any 'startDate' field of field time from Plan collection to Time collection object

ie. `Plan.time.startDate === today`

or if matches any group and start date in exceptions

ie `Plan.group === Plan.time.exceptions.group && Plan.time.exceptions.startDate === today`

If the second condition group cannot be matched is also ok I can filter them out in script.

```
const dateRangeToday = [ '2021-01-23T00:00:00.000Z', '2021-01-23T23:59:59.999Z' ];
Plan.aggregate([
  { $match: { status: 'Planning' } },
  { $lookup: { from: 'time', localField: 'time', foreignField: '_id', as: 'time' } },
  { $unwind: '$time' },
  { $unwind: '$time.exceptions' },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { 'time.startDate': { $gte: dateRangeToday[0], $lte: dateRangeToday[1] } },
        {
          $and: [
            { 'time.exceptions.startDate': { $gte: dateRangeToday[0] } }  ,
            { 'time.exceptions.startDate': { $lte: dateRangeToday[1] } }  
            
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

But always returning 0 documents. are my date queries fine for parent n subdocument. where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expression match, try [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) if you want to match 2 internal fields,

```
{ $expr: { $eq: ["$group", "$time.exceptions.group"] } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ft6SWTgG89w)

---

Question's second edit for ,

> *But always returning 0 documents.*:

You have to convert your date type from string to date type:

```
const dateRangeToday = [ 
  new Date('2021-01-23T00:00:00.000Z'), 
  new Date('2021-01-23T23:59:59.999Z') 
];
```

Comment: thanks but the main problem is can't select dates although I have dates in for todays date

Comment: thanks it did the trick. In find it works with string but in aggregate it worked with Date, anything on that if you can add to the answer that would be great